# Cannot Authenticate Salesforce in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, authentication, salesforce

I'm getting an error (INVALID_SESSION_ID) when trying to send an authenticated GET request to Salesforce.com.

Here is the plug-in in its entirety, which basically just outputs the body of the REST response to whatever page has the [MembershipTables] shortcode:

```
    if (!class_exists('WP_Http')) {
        include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php');
    }

    // This is obviously the real username
    $username = 'xxxx@xxxx.xxx';
    // And this is obviously the real password concatonated with the security token
    $password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    function getMembershipTables() {
    $api_url = 'https://na15.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/directory';
    $headers = array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password"));
    $args = array('headers' => $headers);
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $result = $request->request($api_url, $args);
    $body = $result['body'];
    echo "$body";
    }

    add_shortcode( 'MembershipTables', 'getMembershipTables' );
```

I should note that I can successfully hit this endpoint with Curl, though I use a session token I get from Salesforce using the old SOAP API to keep it equivalent (i.e., no client id/secret).

Am I doing something wrong with WP_Http?  Or cannot I not authenticate a salesforce.com request using basic auth?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The salesforce API does not support Basic authentication, you need to call it with a sessionId. You can obtain a sessionId by various methods include interactive & programatic [OAuth2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=intro_understanding_authentication.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/intro_understanding_authentication.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) flows, and via a [Soap login](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call.

Answer (score 0):

Basis Interactive had a similar problem to solve.  When I worked on the project I opted to  to call the SalesForce CRM via the preset form plugin and a custom JS Cookie PHP Wordpress Plugin.   We had this problem easily resolved by developing custom calls to SalesForce CRM via a getRequest in PHP passing data to the SalesForce CRM.

Test Site in Use:

http://newtest.medullan.com/wp/?page_id=3089

Here is the code and recycle the logical queries

Download Link:

http://basisinteractive.net/webdesign.html#wordpress